# Worldfire and Protection

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have [Progenitus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProgenitus%5d) on my side of the field, and my friend plays [Worldfire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorldfire%5d). Would Progenitus still be on the field after Worldfire resolves or is he also exiled since he has "Protection from everything?"

Comment: Protection (only) prevents DEBT: Damage, Enchant/Equip/Fortify, Blocking and Targeting.

Answer (score 2):

Your [Progenitus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProgenitus%5d) would still be exiled.

According to the Gatherer rulings:

> **2/1/2009**: “Protection from everything” means the following: Progenitus can't be blocked, Progenitus can't be enchanted or equipped, Progenitus can't be the target of spells or abilities, and all damage that would be dealt to Progenitus is prevented.
>
> **2/1/2009**: Progenitus can still be affected by effects that don't target it or deal damage to it (such as Day of Judgment).

Since [Worldfire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorldfire%5d) doesn't target anything, Progenitus will be exiled along with everything else.

Comment: Recommend removing the "Yes"; because the question asks which it is; not a yes-or-no.